# How do I make it such that PowerPoint for macOS doesn't cause haptic feedback when dragging an image?

Tags: macos, ms-office

Whenever I drag an image across the guide lines, I get a haptic feedback on the trackpad that I'm currently using to drag the image which is very distracting.

How can disable this "feature"?

Comment: I can understand how this haptic feedback might be cool. But once you have more than a handful of objects on the page, dragging just turns into a awkward buzzing.

Answer (score 8):

The haptic feedback can be disabled in PowerPoint settings:

> PowerPoint > Preferences > Edit > Smart Guides > Enable haptic feedback

[image]